# In $\triangle ABC$, find intersection of the angle bisectors to midpoint

Tags: geometry

Let triangle $\triangle ABC$ have side lengths $AB = 7$, $BC = 8$, and $CA = 9$, and let M and D
be midpoint of BC and the foot of the altitude from A to BC , respectively. Let E
and F lie on AB and AC, respectively, such that $m\angle{AEM} = m\angle{AFM} = 90$ . Let P be the intersection of the angle bisectors of $\angle{AED}$ and $\angle{AFD}$ .
Find MP.

We can easily calculate $BD=2$, $AD=3\sqrt5$, $MF=4/3 \sqrt 5$, $EM=12/7 \sqrt 5$.

Theoretically, massive coordinates calculation may work things out.

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I don't if this helps. But A,E,D,M,F are concyclic since all these points lie of the circle with diameter AE. MP is perpendicular to BC.

Comment: I see A,E,D,M,F are concyclic in the circle with diameter AM. $\angle{PED} + \angle{PFD} = 45 $. How do you get $MP \perp {BC}$? Still don't know how to calculate PM.

Comment: Can you explain why ${MP} \perp {BC}$? If that's true, I can calculate $\tan \angle {DAM}$, which is the same as $\tan \angle {DFM}$, then I can get $\sin \angle {PFD}$. I can also get $\cos \angle {FMC}$ which is $\sin \angle {PMF}$. In $\triangle {PMF}$, I can get $PM$ using Law of Sine.

Comment: What's the source of the problem?